# Take current date issue

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, formula

I have two cells **A1** and **A2**. What I want is for **A1** to take the current date mm/dd/yyyy if A2 has a value bigger than zero (0). For this I used the following formula in A1:

```
=IF(E2>0;(TODAY()))
```

So if a cell in A2 is for example **60** then A1 will be `11/03/2015`.
If I save this and reopen it the next day the values in A1 will automatically change into the new date. This is something that I don't like as I want to use this method to keep track of my expenses each day. So if I type an amount in A2 I want A1 to give me the current date and keep it.

So how can I get the current date without worrying that every time I reopen the file they will change?

Comment: You're going to have to use VBA.  As you noticed, using `=Today()` anywhere will update to the day the file is opened.  Using VBA, you could have a macro that waits for your column A to change and then takes the result and pastes value over it.  Try doing this in the macro recorder (do your formula, copy and paste values), and post back any thoughts.

Comment: To be honest I am not familiar with VBA. Can you give me some more info on how to do this? Perhaps an article so I can read about it? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: @pnuts A1 and A2 are columns!! not cells ... a cell is determined by the name of row and column together!!!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a macro, not a formula. I am assuming you're performing this operation on COLUMNS not ROWS. EG: A1 and B1, NOT A1 and A2.

What is the difference?

Macro: Can be triggered one time on an event.

Formula: Given a input, it constantly re-evaluates the result.

Step 1) Press Alt+F11, this will open up the code editor in VBA.

Step 2) Copy and paste the code below into your 'sheet' that your formula resides in.

Step 3) Save your workbook as a macro-enabled spreadsheet. (xlsm).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    If (Target.Columns.Count = 1 And Target.Column = 2 And Target.Rows.Count = 1) Then
        'Check every row, currently this will get executed once
        For Each cell In Target.Cells
            'Make sure the value is a number
            If (IsNumeric(cell.Value)) Then
                'Make sure the value is greater than 0
                If (cell.Value > 0) Then
                    'Check to make sure the date column is empty, so it only ever gets written once
                    'Note: You can remove the if statement below, if you want it to get re-evaluated every time you make a change
                    If (Target.Worksheet.Cells(cell.row, 1).Value = "") Then
                        'Using the current modified row, set column 1 to Today
                        'Note: Now() is the same as Today in VBA
                        Target.Worksheet.Cells(cell.row, 1).Value = Now()
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    End If  
End Sub
```

Note: This macro only gets executed if you modify one row at a time, you can change it to work on multiple cells by removing the 'Target.Rows.Count = 1' part of the FIRST 'if' statement.

Note2: The last nested 'if' statement can be removed if you want the date to be re-evaluated any time a change is made to column 2. (aka Column B, in VBA columns are referenced via number, not letters).

Note3: If you really need it to work via rows, try to understand this macro by stepping through it with the debugger, and reconstruct it. Keying off of Rows instead of Columns.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I will let you know about this one :) thanks a lot.